# Fixed terminal status lineS instead of shell prompt?

Tags: terminal

It is common to cram useful information in the Unix shell prompt, but I have too many things I want to keep an eye on to fit it all in one prompt: current Gnu screen window, current directory, current time, hostname, current git branch, phase of the moon, you-name-it.

It would be saner to have a *fixed status **region*** at the bottom (or top) of the terminal to show all this information, and leave the prompt alone.  (I wrote "fixed status region" rather than "fixed status line" because I don't want to limit myself to one line.)

(This region, of course, would not be affected by normal interactive output.)

Is there a standard Unix to implement such a fixed status region, and would allow me to update it through the `precmd` function?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1398132/432690

Answer (score 2):

You could split your screen horizontally in `screen`, set one area the size you want for your *status region*, and run some `watch -t cat ~/.status` in it and then fill the content of that `~/.status` in your `precmd()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your terminal supports terminal addressing, save cursor and restore cursor, this might work:

```
PS1="$(tput sc;tput cup 0 0;tput rev;tput el)\u@\h \W$( tput rc;tput sgr0)\$ "
```

But beware that the command can be difficult to edit as the shell gets confused about where it is in the input buffer.

In `bash`, you can tell it to ignore the cursor control sequences using backslash-square brackets:

```
PS1="\[$(tput sc;tput cup 0 0;tput rev;tput el)\]\u@\h \W\[$( tput rc;tput sgr0)\]\$ "
```

If this doesn't work, try sending the output direct to the terminal:

```
TOSL=$(tput sc;tput cup 0 0;tput rev;tput el)
FROMSL=$(tput sgr0; tput rc)
PS1='$(echo -n "$TOSL $LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME ${PWD/#$HOME/~}$FROMSL">/dev/tty)\$ '
```

Comment: The use of `\[`...`\]` here is not quite right to avoid confusing the prompt.  Brackets are needed not just for non-printing escape sequences, but for anything which doesn't print *on the line where the user input will be entered.* This means the entire status line portion of PS1 should be inside the brackets, with only the "`\$ `" outside.

Answer (score 1):

This year [2023], ten years after your question, I got bored one day and wrote a little thing called "Basta" (Bash Status line).

https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/basta/about/

It's small script you source from your `~/.bashrc` file which gives you a protected status line at the bottom of the screen, showing the date, time, host and working directory (abbreviated  to fit, if necessary).

The time updates while Bash is waiting for input!

Comment: Source links seem to be dead, unfortunately

Comment: @InterLinked You probably ran into my over-aggressive ban filter.

Comment: @InterLinked Someone accessing the Bata repo, leaving a httpd log like this got banned for 1 day: `207.241.*.* - - [24/Mar/2024:15:26:46 -0700] "GET /cgit/basta/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10585 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/605.1.15"`.  The reason is probably my rule against too many browsers in the agent string. We have Mozilla, Gecko, Chrome, Safari, sheesh ... that looks spammy, like not a human being with a normal browser. You can have two, that's it: your actual software and one popular one it's compatible with.

Comment: That isn't my user agent, but from the moment I first when to the link, it hasn't been working, apart from the "about" page

Comment: Another agent string got banned about 40 minutes ago accessing the Basta repo: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`, IPv4 address `172.58.*.*`. That was the only access today, Pacific time. Yesterday, since my previous comment, someone reporting as `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0` visted the `/about` page without being banned, but didn't access the code.

Comment: That wasn't me either... anyways, your "over-aggressive ban filter" is just plain stupid and wrong, those look like normal, perfectly acceptable user agents. If you're going to block anything with Mozilla, Chrome, and Safari in the user agent, then you may as well block most browsers

Comment: @InterLinked Yes, those are acceptable user agents *by themselves*. Not in a combination of three or more in a single access.

Comment: No, that is simply false. Commercial Google Chrome for examples advertises all three of "Mozilla", "Chrome", and "Safari". Sorry, but your algorithm is just wrong. If you want to block legitimate users, you are doing the right thing. As it is, your algorithm has a lot of false positives

Comment: @InterLinked I disabled the rule, in any case (and cleared the bans). Anything with even a small false positive rate (let alone high one) is a nonstarter.

Answer (score 0):

AT&T Unix had `sysline` command, which provided a status line for terminals that don't have it in hardware.  Maybe there is a GNU equivalent by now...